# Android app using cordova, backbone.js,localstorage

Tags: backbone.js, cordova

I am developing an Android app using backbone.js and need to keep user details in sessions or local storage.  I am using the following code to  save the data in localstorage.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("ICName", data.ICName);
window.localStorage.setItem("ICID", data.ICID);
window.localStorage.setItem("IAID", data.IAID);
window.localStorage.setItem("ialastname", data.ialastname);
window.localStorage.setItem("iafirstname", data.iafirstname);
window.localStorage.setItem("IAPhone", data.IAPhone);
window.localStorage.setItem("IAEmail", data.IAEmail);
window.localStorage.setItem("fax", data.fax);
```

I am trying to retrieve them in other page like this

```
$('#txtAdusterName').val( window.localStorage.getItem("iafirstname") + window.localStorage.getItem("ialastname"));
alert('Session  ' + window.localStorage.getItem("iafirstname") + window.localStorage.getItem("ialastname"));
$('#txtadjusterphone').val(window.localStorage.getItem("IAPhone"));
alert('Session  '+window.localStorage.getItem("IAPhone"));
alert('Session  ' + window.localStorage.getItem("IAEmail"));
alert('Session  ' + window.localStorage.getItem("ICName"));
$('#txtAdjusterEmail').val(window.localStorage.getItem("IAEmail"));
$('#txtCompany').val(window.localStorage.getItem("ICName"));
```

The problem I am facing is,when it was run on any browser it was working fine.  I was able to get the data from local storage. But when  it was installed in a phone(android) it was not getting the data. I also used SessionStorage("KEY","Value"). Can any one help to get out of this?   Thanks in advance......

Comment: Well, debug your app for errors. localStorage alone works fine on pretty much any browser.

Comment: it was working in browser but it was not working in Android mobile

Comment: I get that; you are probably using some newer features that are not supported in all versions of Android. Check the browser console for errors. Also, `localStorage.fax("fax", data.fax)` should probably read `.setItem`.